# Data are not being saved into database even though fillable have been set

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-many

in my database I am trying to save my data into database, table fish, but only my bear_id is being saved and not the fish_location or fish_type. Can anyone help?

Information: one bear have many fish (one to many relationship)

Contoller:

```
 public function submit(Request $request)
{

$bear= Session::get('data');


$test = array();
$test['fish_location'] = $request->fish_location;
$test['fish_type'] = $request->fish_type;
$fish = new fish;
$fish = fish::create([$test]);
$fish->bears()->associate($bear);
$fish->save();
return ('thank you');

}
```

fish model:

```
class fish extends Eloquent
{
        protected $fillable = array('fish_type', 'fish_location', 'bear_id');


    public function bears() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\bear');
    }
```

fish table:

```
Schema::create('fishs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';  
    $table->string('fish_location');
    $table->string('fish_type'); 
    $table->integer('bear_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `create()` method expects an array of data to set. What you've actually passed in is an array that contains the array of data. Remove the surrounding `[]` and you should be good:

```
$fish = fish::create($test);
```

Comment: I got this error when I try to remove [], "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in "

Comment: @blastme Before your call to `create()`, what is the result of `dd($bear, $test);`?

Comment: bear {#199 ▼
  #fillable: array:13 [▶]
  #table: "bears"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #connection: "mysql"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
  #attributes: array:16 [▶]
  #original: array:16 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}

Comment: array:2 [▼
  "fish_type" => array:1 [▶]
  "fish_location" => array:1 [▶]
]

Comment: I got this and I don't really know how to use dd so I can't really tell what is the problem here

Comment: @blastme Your `dd()` output shows that both `fish_type` and `fish_location` are both arrays. They need to be scalar values. You either need to change the request input so that they are not arrays, or you need to handle the request input to get the proper data out of the array.

Comment: But how do I do that? Do you have any example for me for reference because I thought all I need to do is "$test['fish_type'] = $request->fish_type;" to get them

Comment: @blastme I'm assuming your input names in the HTML end in square brackets (i.e. `name="fish_type[]"`, `name="fish_location[]"`. If these values are not supposed to be arrays, remove the ending brackets, so they are treated as scalar values and not arrays (i.e. `name="fish_type"`, `name="fish_location").

Comment: I require fish_type[] and fish_location[] because they are in a html table in my blade.php where when the user click on the add button, it will add another row and I heard that I need to put their name with a [] bracket so that it can be save, is there no other way to di it other than changing the name?

Comment: @blastme Okay, so you're expecting fish_type and fish_location to be arrays. How are you expecting to handle that data? `$request->fish_type` will give you the array of data that was submitted. You can't store an array in the database. What do you expect the fish_type field to store in the database?

Comment: @blastme For example, if you just want to store a comma separated list of the array data, you would do `$test['fish_type'] = implode(',', $request->fish_type);`.

Comment: The implode function works tks a lot !! But my bear_id for some reason became 0 any idea?

Comment: Oh nvm it was some typo. But still tks a lot, was having trouble with this for quite some time :)

Answer (score 0):

call $fish->save(); before $fish->bears()->associate($bear);

```
$fish->save();    
$fish->bears()->associate($bear);
```

Or try

```
$bear= Session::get('data');
$fish = new fish;
$fish->fish_location=$request->fish_location
$fish->fish_type =$request->fish_type;
$fish->save();
$fish->bears()->associate($bear);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error after using the codes, "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given". Any idea what to do? I'm using the 2nd method

Comment: And when I try to change it into an array using " $fish= array(); " before the request, it gave me this error "Attempt to assign property of non-object"